# How to debug my code by this error Log in IOS

Tags: ios

Hi my app crashing randomly when I am upgrading my app to new version.

I am getting this error log

```
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x1467b680> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x1454cbd0: Observer: 0x1467b680, Key path: operations, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1454cac0> <NSKeyValueObservance 0x1461b290: Observer: 0x1473bdf0, Key path: operations, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1454cac0> ): An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled. Key path: operations Observed object: <NSOperationQueue: 0x1467bd00>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x1467bd00'} Change: { kind = 1; new = ( "<ASIFormDataRequest: 0x15384200>" ); old = ( ); } Context: 0x0
AgendaNotes-[DocumentManager addToPriorityQueue:]


#   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
0   CoreFoundation  0x30640e8b  
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3ac886c7  objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  0x30640dcd  
3   Foundation  0x310050d3  
4   Foundation  0x30f70c51  
5   Foundation  0x30f708f5  
6   Foundation  0x30f6fff1  
7   Foundation  0x31012b13  
8   NyNotes     0x0003d329  -[DocumentManager addToPriorityQueue:]                      
9   NyNotes         0x000453a7  -[DocumentManager asyncRequestInsertToken:]
10  NyNotes         0x00017267  -[AgendaHandler handleAPNSToken:]
11  NyNotes         0x00014ea9  -[AgendaHandler loginResponse:withResponse:]
12  NyNotes     0x0004057f  -[DocumentManager responseLogin:]
13  NyNotes         0x00042edd  -[DocumentManager requestHasFinishedCredentialRequest:]
14  MyNotes     0x00042fc1  -[DocumentManager requestHasFinished:]
15  MyNotes     0x00025495  -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished]
16  Foundation  0x31024fdb  
17  CoreFoundation  0x3060bf27  
18  CoreFoundation  0x3060b3ef  
19  CoreFoundation  0x30609bdf  
20  CoreFoundation  0x30574541  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
21  CoreFoundation  0x30574323  CFRunLoopRunInMode
22  GraphicsServices    0x352782eb  GSEventRunModal
23  UIKit           0x32e2b1e5  UIApplicationMain
24  MyNotes     0x00009907  main
25  MyNotes     0x00008a18  start
```

I am not able to get anything form this error log.

Comment: You didn't get `An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the answer:
An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled. Key path: operations Observed object: {name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x1467bd00'} Change: { kind = 1; new = ( "<**ASIFormDataRequest**: 0x15384200>" ); old = ( ); } Context: 0x0

I think you are definitely better of using either an operation on your own. There are excellent examples for this here on stack overflow. If you are building for iOS 7 only then use NSURLConnection. Makes things even simpler and is way more powerful thanks to the background operations.

If you want to debug the ASI framework I suggest add a breakpoint for all exemptions and see if you can nail this down.